# Liquid Sort Array of strings alphabetically and label them

Tags: arrays, sorting, shopify, liquid

I have a sorted array of strings, and now I want to print them out while labelling them.

For example, if my array is [ '1_array_content', '3_array_content', 'apple', 'ant', 'bucket']

Then I want to print them out like this: How can I add the first alphabet as a label? And how does that work for numerical first alphabets (all of them will fall under the [0-9] label.

**[0-9]**

1_array_content

3_array_content

**[a]**

ant

apple

**[b]**

bucket

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have two problems to solve here:

- The main which is to display first character once as label
- The secondary one which concern number case

Here is a possible solution (not tested, explanations below):

```
{% assign numbers_label_displayed = false %}
{% assign letter_labels = '' %}

{% for item in array.items %}

    {% case item.first %}

    {% when '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' %}

        {% unless numbers_label_displayed %}
            [0-9]
            {% assign numbers_label_displayed = true %}
        {% endunless %}

    {% else %}

        {% unless letter_labels contains item.first %}
            {{ item.first | append:']' | prepend:'[' }}
            {% assign letter_labels = letter_labels | append: item.first | append: ' ' %}
        {% endunless %}

    {% endcase %}

    {{ item }}

{% endfor %}
```

First, I init two variables which will help to check if labels have been already displayed. The first one is a boolean to handle the "numbers" case, the second one store all labels that have already been displayed.

Then I init the loop through array and handle both cases: numbers and letters. I use  control flow case/when becaus it is less verbious and lighter than if/else and allow to manage the two problems globally.

I list numbers in the first when and assign a else to handle the letters.

To handle number case, I set an unless condition for the boolean var, then I display label for numbers and set my boolean variable to true so next iteration won't display it again.

To handle letter case, I set an unless condition checking if letter has already been stored in string var. If it doesn't, I display the letter and add it to string var. If it does, the unless condition allow to not display it as label again.

HTH